# Is it possible to move another element below a position: sticky?

Tags: html, css

Hope I can explain my question so you understand :)
I have a sidebar with position: sticky which moves the sidebar when scrolling down the page. My problem is now, when I scroll the page complete down, there is another element which get covered from the sticky sidebar. Is it possible to move that element down also when reaching it with the sidebar?

Please see my page for reference, so you´ll know what I mean. The clue would be to do it with css only?

https://heimprofi.shop/bodenbelaege-sockelleisten/sockelleisten/altberliner-hamburger-profil/

Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly is being covered up in this case? I guess I'm not seeing any immediate issues from that link you attached

Comment: Ah sorry, you need to have a look on one or two products first. There appear the last seen products row :) - http://prntscr.com/ld8s08

Comment: sticky has the same problems/features than absolute. If you don't want an element to be covered by a sticky element, you've to keep the area clean :) by not displaying anything there. You'll have to make some calculations and tests in JS (and try not to make an element jump without any reason; users'd be very surprised).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So as I understand well, there is no simple css solution for that problem :)